# Setting variable to a list with lists inside as reference

Tags: python

I'm trying to set `area` to `List` except if a wanted to change `area`, `List` would stay the same. So I did a for loop that would get each element from `List` and append it to area but that seems to **almost** be working, like if I was missing a step. Can somebody explain to me why it is not working? Preferably don't send code because I want to code it myself followed with an explanation, but if you really need to its fine.

```
List = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

area = []

for Map_list in range(len(List)):
    area.append([])
    for Map_index in List[Map_list]:
        area[Map_list].append(List[Map_list][Map_index])
```

For comparison:

```
print(f'area: {area}')
print(f'List: {List}')
```

Comment: Could you share what's the output you want to get like?

Comment: I want this output `print(f'area: {area}')` to be the same as this output `print(f'List: {List}')` 
But instead, the outputs are different

Comment: Isn't just `area = [*List]` what you want? By the way, it's nice to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) styling when coding in Python. Try to use Snake Case when declaring variables. (`list_` instead of `List`, `map_list` instead of `Map_List` and so on)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, but thank you for the tip on using list_ instead

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I did not take in consideration that the elements of the list `List` were mutable objects (other lists). You are right, by doing just that, it would not word for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for Map_list` loop sets `Map_list` successively to the index of each list in `List` so those sublists can be used as sources for copying.

The `for Map_index in List[Map_list]:` goes through the *values*, not the *indexes* of the elements of the sublist.  But the statement

`area[Map_list].append(List[Map_list][Map_index])`

uses `Map_index` as an index, so it doesn't have the desired effect.  It uses data from the sublist as an index on the sublist.

To get the desired effect of changes to `area` having no effect on `List`, you should use the `deepcopy` function from the `copy` module of the standard library.  This also means you don't need your nested for-loops any more.

The suggested solution of `area = [*List]` solves the problem of making a list that looks the same, but does not satisfy the requirement that changes to `List` should not affect `area`.  Demonstration:

```
>>> list1 = [[1]]
>>> list2 = [*list1]
>>> list1
[[1]]
>>> list2
[[1]]
>>> list1[0][0] = 99
>>> list1
[[99]]
>>> list2
[[99]]
```